# How to detect values in table's column and subtract them to another column?

Tags: r, dataframe, data.table, quantile

**Data**

I'm working with data.table and I'm trying to make a quite difficult manipulation.
My data looks like this:

```
A <- data.table(c("a","a","b","c","d","d"),c(1,2,2,3,4,9),c(1,1,0,0,7,3))
   V1 V2 V3
1:  a  1  1
2:  a  2  1
3:  b  2  0
4:  c  3  0
5:  d  4  7
6:  d  9  3
```

**What I want to do**

I need to detect when there is a value >0 in V3. When it's the case, I need to sum values in V3 that are successively >0 and then subtract them to the sum of corresponding rows in V2, then if the result is lower than the 20% quantile of the sum of corresponding rows in V2, then corresponding rows in V2 get 0, else, split the result in among the corresponding rows in V2.

**Example**

In V3, we have the 2 first row >0. We sum it -> 2, the sum of corresponding row is 3. We subtract it, we obtain 1 which is >= to the 20% quantile so we split it and same for below. The result might be:

```
   V1  V2 V3
1:  a 0.5  1
2:  a 0.5  1
3:  b 2.0  0
4:  c 3.0  0
5:  d 1.5  7
6:  d 1.5  3
```

**EDIT**

When there is a 0, the group of value is finished. I mean, the first group is the first 2 rows, containing 1 and 1 in V3, then there is 0 so the group is finished. Then there is another 0 so we don't take it and then, there is a value >0 which means that another group starts here until another 0.

Comment: what do you mean by 20% quantile? do you mean 20% of the sum?

Comment: I think your example is oversimplified and will result to overfited answers. Can you show some more data? For example can a group have both 0 and non-0 values?

Comment: @Sotos i edited my post to explain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that V1 is also reflecting the locations where V3 > 0, you can use V1 in your grouping by.

```
A[V3 > 0, V2 := ifelse( (sum(V2) - sum(V3)) < 0.2*sum(V2), 0, (sum(V2) - sum(V3)) / .N),
    by=.(V1)]
```

Or if V1 cannot be relied upon, you can create a V1-like grouping on the fly as follows, using `rle`

```
A[, 
    V2 := ifelse(V3 <= 0, V2,
        ifelse(sum(V2) - sum(V3) < 0.2*sum(V2), 0, (sum(V2) - sum(V3)) / .N)),
    by=.(rep(seq_along(rle(V3 > 0)$values), rle(V3 > 0)$lengths))]
```

Comment: This is exactly what i'm looking for, thank you very much